# Velero backup PV freezes whole server

Tags: backup, kubernetes, minio, kind

I am facing an issue while trying to backup a namespace with PV in it: after running command `velero backup create nginx-example-with-pv --include-namespaces nginx-example` i am unable to execute velero commands nor kubectl. After few minutes whole server stops to respond on any commands and i have to reboot it. But backup without PV completes successfully and i am able to restore objects from it.

I am using Kind v0.20.0, Kubernetes 1.27.3, Velero v1.13.0 with inbuilt Restic installation, container Minio minio/mc:latest. For Velero install i am using command:

```
velero install \
    --provider aws \
    --plugins velero/velero-plugin-for-aws:v1.9.0 \
    --bucket velero \
    --secret-file ./credentials-velero \
    --use-volume-snapshots=false \
    --use-node-agent \
    --uploader-type=restic \
    --backup-location-config region=minio,s3ForcePathStyle="true",s3Url=http://$1:$2
```

For Minio and Nginx example install i use a Velero example from [official repo](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/tree/v1.13.0/examples) with annotation `backup.velero.io/backup-volumes: nginx-logs` added into nginx-deployment `.spec.template.metadata.annotations`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: velero

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: velero
  name: minio
  labels:
    component: minio
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: minio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: minio
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: minio
        image: minio/minio:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
        - server
        - /storage
        - --config-dir=/config
        env:
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          value: "minio"
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          value: "minio123"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: "/storage"
        - name: config
          mountPath: "/config"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: velero
  name: minio
  labels:
    component: minio
spec:
  # ClusterIP is recommended for production environments.
  # Change to NodePort if needed per documentation,
  # but only if you run Minio in a test/trial environment, for example with Minikube.
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    component: minio

---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: velero
  name: minio-setup
  labels:
    component: minio
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: minio-setup
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      volumes:
      - name: config
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: mc
        image: minio/mc:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - "mc --config-dir=/config config host add velero http://minio:9000 minio minio123 && mc --config-dir=/config mb -p velero/velero"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: "/config"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx-example
  labels:
    app: nginx

---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-logs
  namespace: nginx-example
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  # Optional:
  # storageClassName: <YOUR_STORAGE_CLASS_NAME>
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: nginx-example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
      annotations:
        pre.hook.backup.velero.io/container: fsfreeze
        pre.hook.backup.velero.io/command: '["/sbin/fsfreeze", "--freeze", "/var/log/nginx"]'
        post.hook.backup.velero.io/container: fsfreeze
        post.hook.backup.velero.io/command: '["/sbin/fsfreeze", "--unfreeze", "/var/log/nginx"]'
        backup.velero.io/backup-volumes: nginx-logs
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-logs
          persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: nginx-logs
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.17.6
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/var/log/nginx"
            name: nginx-logs
            readOnly: false
      - image: ubuntu:bionic
        name: fsfreeze
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/var/log/nginx"
            name: nginx-logs
            readOnly: false
        command:
          - "/bin/bash"
          - "-c"
          - "sleep infinity"


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: my-nginx
  namespace: nginx-example
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

My VM configuration is 4Gb RAM, 4 cores, 60Gb HDD space.

Also i have tried to get workload of kubernetes pods and nodes with `kubectl top`, but in return i'm geting `error: Metrics API not available`.

Will be grateful for any ideas why is it happening and how to resolve it.